# c++ lambda self-passing exception

Tags: c++, exception, lambda, boost-asio

When I run this code, I get std::bad_functon_call exception.
I cannot figure out whats the reason for this exception. 
It's thrown by the async_receive inside receiveCallback.
Is receiveCallback cleared out from the memory before being called?

```
//callback on connection accepted
    std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket* socketPtr)> acceptCallback =
        [this, onMessageReceivedCallback, acceptCallback](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket* socketPtr)
    {
        cout<<"accept: "<<error.message()<<endl;

        const int bufferSize = 100;
        char* message = new char[bufferSize];

        //callback on message received
        std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred)> receiveCallback =
            [message, bufferSize, socketPtr, onMessageReceivedCallback, receiveCallback](const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            onMessageReceivedCallback(message, bytes_transferred);

            socketPtr->async_receive(
            boost::asio::buffer(message, bufferSize),
            receiveCallback);
        };

        socketPtr->async_receive(
            boost::asio::buffer(message, bufferSize),
            receiveCallback);

        //create socket for the next connection
        socketPtr = new tcp::socket(io_service_);
        //continue accepting connections
        acceptor_.async_accept(*socketPtr, std::bind(acceptCallback, std::placeholders::_1, socketPtr));
```

Comment: While the lambda readability and ordering can be nice, it is often difficult due to lifetimes.  It may be worth considering [coroutines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997290/1053968) as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is Undefined Behaviour: when the lambda captures `receiveCallback` by value, `receiveCallback` is not yet initialized so the copy the lambda gets is garbage (with GCC 4.7 I even get a segfault instead of `std::bad_function_call`). `acceptCallback` exhibits the same problem by the way.

An apparent solution would be to capture `receiveCallback` by reference instead of by value, but then it will pose problems related to the lifetime of the object (the `receiveCallback` object must stay alive for the whole duration of the I/O operations, but it gets destroyed as soon as you exit the `accept` lambda).

It's a chicken and egg situation: capture by reference won't work because of lifetime issues, you need capture by value to solve that, but capture by value makes a copy of an uninitialized object so you need capture by reference to solve that. Meh.

Note that `receiveCallback` is incorrect in another way: you capture `message` by value too, which means that whenever the lambda is called you'll end up not with the buffer filled by `boost::asio`, but with a copy of the buffer that was made when the lambda was instantiated (in other words, uninitialized garbage again).

---

Now that the diagnostic is made, how to fix that and write working code?

In my opinion, drop the lambdas altogether. Write a class that will hold your `message` buffer and `onMessageReceivedCallback`, and that has `accept` and `receive` member functions.

Depending on the exact API of `boost::asio` you may need to "wrap" your member functions in `std::function` objects to get callbacks that `asio` can use (`std::mem_fn` is your friend here, don't forget to `std::bind` the first argument of the resulting `std::function` object to the instance of your class).