# Problems with Async_Read function

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

**Introduction**

I'm studying `c++` and `boost/asio` to implement a distributed system, so I need create  an asynchronous tcp server.
The server works like an echo-server but you need make the request first (for example, send text through the socket) and the server just responds the pi number.

**Tcp-connection class used in Main-server class**

```
class tcp_connection
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this <tcp_connection> {
        public:
            typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

            static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service &io_service){
                return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
            }

            tcp::socket &socket(){
                return socket_;
            }

            void start(){
                for(;;){

                    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
                        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                         boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
                    );

                    buffer_ = "Pi: 3.1415\n\0";
                    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
                        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
                }
            }
        private:
            tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
                : socket_(io_service){
            }

            void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
                size_t /*bytes_transferred*/){
            }

             void handle_read(){
            }

            //attr
            tcp::socket socket_;
            std::string buffer_;
    };
```

**Problem**

I've read some tutorials and many questions in stackoverflow. And I can't understand why I've this bug: `error: ‘void (tcp_connection::*)()’ is not a class, struct, or union type`.

I found the error source in this line: `boost::asio::async_read(...)`. If I remove that line, server works fine, but I need understand the `async_read` functionality to implement complex systems later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async_read` expects a handler - a function that will be called when something is read from the socket. This handler should have a specific signature. In your case it should be something like

```
void handle_read(boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_transferred)
```

just because you use it as

```
boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                     boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
```

So you bind `tcp_connection::handle_read` with `this` (kind of) (the first implicit argument to any non-static method) and error code and number of bytes transferred, so expected signature is `void handle_read(boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t bytes_transferred)`. Maybe you need to learn more about how `binding` works: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html

As a bonus:

your

```
for (;;) 
{
    //read
    // write
}
```

is synchronous approach. You need something different if you want to use async one. The main idea is to chain them so your read takes a handler and the handler async writes response taking a write handler and the write handler starts another async read, and so looped.

Comment: One more wonderful "linear" idea: [Coroutines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997290/5112690)

Comment: ok, first of all, the same problem as before but now with your `handle_write`, you bind it the same way as you do `handle_read` but its signature is different, do you see the problem? and `bind` is really old school approach, if your compiler supports lambdas better use them, or check Coroutines suggested by Anno ^^ there're other problems, e.g. with your buffer, check this example how it can be done properly: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: The author of Asio has a great blog entry that [illustrates bind](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html).